# Unauthorized_Payment Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When making PayPal live transaction I get the error.I am using credit/debit card and the country is Myanmar (MYR).
Kindly help

```
{"response":{"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"85b4dde45869","httpStatusCode":401},"httpStatusCode":401},"PAYMENT":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to process a payment using REST API vault card id with Malaysia PayPal business account. PayPal Vault payments are not available in Malaysia country. Please use PayPal payments.